# Rollback Update Operation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I executed an `UPDATE` operation for every row in my table by mistake. Is there any way I can take this back? I use SQL Server 2005.

Comment: are you using full or simple backup mode? Run this `SELECT * FROM sys.databases` and look at `recovery_model_desc` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into same situation but latter used this third party tool and it worked !

http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx

[Read this thread it might help](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c7a1f22a-4487-4499-b663-f0e8776b3069/rollback-sql-update-query?forum=transactsql)

And..
If you have already executed the update query and want to roll back,your only real option is to restore a database backup.

If you are using Full backups, then you should be able to restore the database to a specific point in time.

Comment: thanks for the answer. apexsql is reading log sources right now. but, it says "only every 10th row will be exported into UNDO, REDO and other export scripts". i only need to rollback one operation. if that isn't in the 10th row, is there a work-around for it?

Comment: that is issue with trial version [see here](http://www.apexsql.com/public_support/betas/apexsql_log_beta_readme.txt)..or wait until operation is completed. [or this might help](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log_readme.aspx)

Comment: i don't get your point here. should i pay almost 1000$ to roll back one update operation?

Comment: lol.. Nope,but ! it' shouldn't be that msg what you are getting ! [Try these steps and it should be done](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/recover-sql-server-data-from-accidental-updates/)